# Codeigniter form validation: validate input before sending it to callback function

Tags: codeigniter

I use Codeigniter callback function (please see below the code) and I would like to know if it is checking if the input is alpha_numeric before sending it to callback function or not, because I don't want to pass non-alphanumeric input to my callback function.

```
$this->form_validation->set_rules('code', 'Code', 'alpha_numeric|callback_check_code');

    public function check_code($value) {        

    $this->model_abc->did_check_code($value);
    $this->form_validation->set_message('check_code', 'Please enter the code correctly.');
        }
```

**Update:**

I found out that In Codeigniter rules are ran left to right, as soon as one fails, it stops checking and marks the field as 'not passed validation' and set the message as the first failed rule. So the input will not be passed to my callback function if it is non-alphanumeric.

Comment: extend form_validation library if you want your custom rules

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to write your own rules for existing library then do the following steps:

```
<?php  if ( ! defined('BASEPATH')) exit('No direct script access allowed');


class MY_Form_validation extends CI_Form_validation {

    function __construct($rules = array()) {
        parent::__construct($rules);  
        log_message('debug', '*** Hello from MY_Form_validation ***');
    }


    function check_code($postcode) {
        // Do it according to your need
    }
}
```

and save the file in `application/libraries`. For more information check the following link https://ellislab.com/codeigniter/user-guide/general/creating_libraries.html and check the section **Extending Native Libraries**

#### Update:

First understand hows rules working `'alpha_numeric|callback_check_code'` Validation library check the given rules one by one and set according to the error or value. Means if the `alpha_numeric` and `callback_check_code` both validate the data then it return `$this->form_validate->run() == true`.

Comment: thanks, but my question is 'will it validate the input as alphanumeric before sending it to check_code function' ?

Comment: does it mean that if the input is not alphanumeric, it will not even send the input to callback function?

Comment: it will send, but `$this->form_validate->run()` remain false.

Comment: so it will send non-validated input to function check_code and as I pass that input to database in check_code function, it may cause security problem